scale animation in gridview, animation should overlap the child view
in my gridview there are many childs. in each child there is an imageview. the imageview has some little space to the boarders of the child view wherein the imageview can be scaled bigger.
well i only can scale the imageview within the boarders of the child and the space here is very little. i would like to scale bigger, but when i scale bigger, the imageview is cutted at the boarders of the child view.
but the neighbour child has some little space again, and there is space to the imageview again. is there an opportunity to scale the imageview accross the boarders of the childs view without being cutted? so that i can use the space of the neighbour child view to scale bigger?
someone would say to use smaller imageviews, but that makes it look bad.
thank you!
i tried some different scale types, but in every case the image view is cutted at the boarders of the child view. i would like to scale over the child view.
i used following code to scale.
imageview.animate().scaleX(1.1f).scaleY(1.1f).setDuration(250ms);
the animation works correctly, but is cutted at the boarders of the child view.
is there a possibility to animate accross the boarders into the neighbours field?
